# How can we use lbfgs_minimize in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have been unable to reproduce [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/optimizer/lbfgs_minimize) from tensorflow having tensorflow 2.0 installed.

This is the original snippet:

```
# A high-dimensional quadratic bowl.
ndims = 60
minimum = np.ones([ndims], dtype='float64')
scales = np.arange(ndims, dtype='float64') + 1.0

# The objective function and the gradient.
def quadratic(x):
    value = tf.reduce_sum(scales * (x - minimum) ** 2)
    return value, tf.gradients(value, x)[0]

start = np.arange(ndims, 0, -1, dtype='float64')
optim_results = tfp.optimizer.lbfgs_minimize(
  quadratic, initial_position=start, num_correction_pairs=10,
  tolerance=1e-8)

with tf.Session() as session:
    results = session.run(optim_results)
# Check that the search converged
assert(results.converged)
# Check that the argmin is close to the actual value.
np.testing.assert_allclose(results.position, minimum)
```

Which does not work with the following error:

> RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.

If I change the code and have gradient tape instead like the following:

```
def quadratic(x):

    x = tf.Variable(x, dtype='float64')
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        value = tf.reduce_sum(scales * (x - minimum) ** 2)
    grad = t.gradient(value, x)

    return value, grad
```

I also get the following error:

> TypeError: Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.

In general anything I tried didn't work and I don't know how I can use lbfgs in tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: This blog post explains all the details and provides a reproducible example. 
https://pychao.com/2019/11/02/optimize-tensorflow-keras-models-with-l-bfgs-from-tensorflow-probability/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) in your objective function so it is executed as a graph, then you will be able to use [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np

# A high-dimensional quadratic bowl.
ndims = 60
minimum = tf.ones([ndims], dtype='float64')
scales = tf.range(ndims, dtype='float64') + 1.0

# The objective function and the gradient.
@tf.function
def quadratic(x):
    value = tf.reduce_sum(scales * (x - minimum) ** 2)
    return value, tf.gradients(value, x)[0]

start = tf.range(ndims, 0, -1, dtype='float64')
optim_results = tfp.optimizer.lbfgs_minimize(
  quadratic, initial_position=start, num_correction_pairs=10,
  tolerance=1e-8)

# Check that the search converged
print(optim_results.converged.numpy())
# True

# Check that the argmin is close to the actual value.
print(np.allclose(optim_results.position.numpy(), minimum.numpy()))
# True
```

Comment: I still get this error: Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.

Comment: @alireSaRanjbar What versions do you have? I have just tested this snippet with TensorFlow 2.0.0 and TFP 0.8.0 and it works.

Comment: I also use on tensorflow 2.0.0 but in Jupyter notebook. I will still check if there is a version related problem

Comment: seems like the problem was that I had to install tensorflow-probability!:)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a little to the answer by @jdehesa - it can also be useful to use [tfp.math.value_and_gradient](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/math/value_and_gradient) in this case, which will create the gradient tape for you if you are using eager mode. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

ndims = 60
minimum = tf.ones([ndims], dtype="float64")
scales = tf.range(ndims, dtype="float64") + 1.0


def quadratic(x):
    value = tf.reduce_sum(scales * (x - minimum) ** 2)
    return value


start = tf.range(ndims, 0, -1, dtype="float64")

optim_results = tfp.optimizer.lbfgs_minimize(
    lambda x: tfp.math.value_and_gradient(quadratic, x),
    initial_position=start,
    num_correction_pairs=10,
    tolerance=1e-8,
)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that function (I don't really have much experience with TFP), but it does seem like the more natural solution (solves the problem and simplifies the wrapped function, without forcing you to use `tf.function`).